# Notepad++ does not highlight css inside HTML file

Tags: html, css, notepad++

In Notepad++, there is no syntax highlighting for CSS inside a HTML file. Is it possible to enable it?

[image]

Comment: You might get a better response on http://www.superuser.com maybe

Comment: Another woebegone victim of the Close Plague of 2013. From the [home](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) page: "Notepad++ is a free ... source code editor".  I.e. primarily for programming.  (Notepad++ has today [3424 tagged questions on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always just create a second np++ file and mark the language as CSS, then once I'm done copy it over to the HTML file. :)

May not answer your exact question, but that's the way I work around it.

Answer (score 6):

This question has been answered in superuser [Different Language Syntax Highlighting](https://superuser.com/questions/235320/different-language-syntax-highlighting-within-same-file). To sum it up, np++ does not support this feature with HTML and CSS, but it does with HTML and JS. There are a few links in the responses to the question which should be helpful in finding a tool that does support multiple languages.

My suggestion is to go to np++ and request the feature. If enough of us do it then maybe they will pay attention.

Answer (score 0):

Try another editor similar to Notepad++, SynWrite, it has such a CSS feature.