# Code inside <style> tags not working/showing up in Notepad++

Tags: html, notepad++

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
          <title>Earth Game</title>
```

This is the code below that is not showing up in Notepad++, any ideas why?

```
    <style>
    canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: transparent;
        }
    </style>
```

Everything else is showing up as code, just the code above in the Style tags.

```
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <!-- The canvas for the panning background -->
    <canvas id="background" width="600" height="360">
        Your browser does not support canvas. Please try again with a different browser.
    </canvas>
    <script src="EarthGamejs"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**What it looks like :**
[image: What it looks like]

Comment: This can be caused by a browser add-on (eg. add-blockers). Try disabling all the extensions and check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the code isn't collapsed, to do so check on the left of your code in np++, you should see a small square with a plus sign inside it, try clicking on it.

**Edit:** Notepad++ doesn't support CSS highlighting in an HTML file. One option you have is to create a new css file, do what you have to do with the css and then paste it back in the html file.

[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366254/notepad-does-not-highlight-css-inside-html-file)

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Comment: @putvande Why? It's a possible answer (in fact, I'd say it's the most probable answer).

Comment: I dont think that is the problem, ive only just started this and come across this problem!

Comment: If this is not a code-folding issue, then you might want to alter your question to describe what you're seeing and what you expect to see. Maybe add a screenshot?

Comment: I dont think i can add screenshots as im not level 10 yet, The code inside the <style> tags is black. I assumed that it should be a colour considering most of the other code is.

Comment: I see what you mean now. CSS is not coloured when you're using HTML's syntax highlighting in Notepad++.

Comment: @SeanCoyne post a link to your screenshot and somebody will embed it for you